# Why td of table loose their width inside a div (for scrolling table)

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, width

I am working on a table with horizontal and vertical scrolling with fixed header, footer, left and right columns. I am near to solution but there is problem with some style.

**Problem**
I use Div and put table inside it with fixed `width` and `overflow` hidden. But when I apply `width` and `overflow` property to div, the `TDs` of `table` inside div loose their own `width`.  Here is what I want to try

```
<div id="scroll-table">
        <div class="row2 col2"><!-- it is center of my table with more data-->
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                    <td>N</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

//*style*//

```
        * {
            background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        }

        .row2.col2 {
            width:200px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        table td {
            width:50px;

        }
```

I also play with `position` but no success. 
Can you explain me how to get width of TDs (not with padding).
May be it is partially duplicate of some questions but I found all unrelated.

Comment: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or fail.

Comment: Not enough infos as said above +1 !. have you tryed : table-layout:fixed; on table element ?

Comment: no table-layout:fixed not work. But i found solution that i have to give width to table that is equal to (No of td * width of td). how stupid  i am?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution. i have to give width to table itself so TDs think that the have large room to expand.

```
table {
    width:(no. of TDs * Width of single td);
}
table td {
    width:(width of td);
}
```